# how find column nameswhich has particular value in snowflake for a particular schema

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how find column names which has particular value in snowflake for a particular schema,

for e.g to find columns with particular name we can use the below query,

```
Use DatabaseName
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where column_name ilike 'ColName'
```

how do we find a particular value

Comment: Hi - do you mean find a column with a particular column name or find a column that contains a particular value (as part of a record)?

Comment: I want to find a column that has a particular value. The schema may have more than 300 tables

Comment: Please describe an example on how the data would look (tables, columns, rows..) and what results you would expect.