# how to find column names which has particular value in snowflake for a particular schema. The schema may have more than 300 tables

Tags: sql, database, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Basically search for all the columns which has a specific value in multiples tables in a schema

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? [how find column nameswhich has particular value in snowflake for a particular schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571175/how-find-column-nameswhich-has-particular-value-in-snowflake-for-a-particular-sc)

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, there is a 'COLUMNS' view which has this information. You can use the following commands:

```
use <Database_Name>;
select 
    column_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where
    table_schema='<schema_name>' 
        and column_name like '%value%'
```